# convert multiple powershell GUI to exe file

Tags: powershell

I have problem to compile my script files to exe, in my project using multi ps1 files that extended in another ps1 file also using XAML for show UI, for example when running login.ps1, shows you the login page if enter correct username and password The login page closes and the menu page(menu.ps1 in backend working) opens and so on... . how can i compile multi scripts to exe.
I trying use ps2exe for this but ps2exe convert one ps1 file to exe, also F2KO.
Thanks for help me.

Comment: Hi you can insert file 1 to file 2 as a loging fuction make 1 file ,and the file compile with ps2exe .

Comment: *Why* do you want to convert your scripts to an executable (`exe`) file in the first place? If this a attempt to [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) of hardcoded passwords, then be aware that your scripts can be easily decompiled using the command `Executable.exe -extract:C:\Source.ps1`

Comment: hi Kemal k thanks for recommend . I try this.

Comment: hi iRon. because I need compress multi ps1 files to one file and working perfectly. for the password I use `secure string` ,